# How do I know where (from which directory) the process is commanded?

Tags: directory, process

I am running a simulation that is commanded to begin at some directory, but don't remember from which directory I commanded the simulation. I'm using python for running the simulation, so

```
ps aux | grep PID
```

only shows where the executing program is located. (/usr/bin/python). However, I want to know where the command is operated from the very initial point, where the file I'm running is located.

I would greatly appreciate any helpful comments!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'll want to use the `history` command to see which command you actually used?

Answer (score 1):

To see the path of the python script, you can normally see it with `ps` (using the `w`, wide, option if needed):

```
~% ps ugxw | grep python
romano    2136  0.0  0.2  10524  4132 ?        S    09:13   0:00 python /home/romano/software/wallpap/bg_slideshow.py
romano    5839  0.0  0.0   4440   832 pts/1    S+   10:00   0:00 grep python
```

For example, process 2136 is the script `/home/romano/software/wallpap/bg_slideshow.py`. 
If you want to know which is the working directory of the process, do

```
~% ls -l /proc/2136/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 romano romano 0 Nov 11 10:04 /proc/2136/cwd -> /home/romano
```

The process is running with `/home/romano` as its current directory.

In the file `/proc/2136/cmdline` there is the full command line specification --- the same you see in `ps`, with the commands and argument separated by 0-valued bytes (to preserve the spaces). You can see it on your terminal with

```
% cat /proc/2136/cmdline | tr "\0" " "
python /home/romano/software/wallpap/bg_slideshow.py %
```

where "tr" prints a space for each "nul" character found. (the spurious % at the end is due to the file not ending with a newline char).

The /proc filesystem is a really useful tool --- the full documentation is a bit "hard" but it's often useful to have a link to it: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use the `which` command. For example, `which ifconfig` outputs the location of the ifconfig command.